# Grav plugin "Editable with ContentTools" doesn't work

Tags: plugins, grav

I've manually unzip the plugin package under `/user/plugins`, renamed the folder to `editable-contenttools`, copied `editable-contenttools.yaml` to `/user/config/plugins` and under `/admin/plugins` I see that the plugin is enabled.

Next I've added `[editable name="region-0"]` before text in `default.md` and `[/editable]` after  the text and added `editable: true` after `login: true` under `access: > site:` in `/user/accounts/admin.yaml`

But when I open a page with the text at the front-end (using build-in Quark theme), I don't see any editor and any possibility to edit content.

I also disable `session:split` but nothing helps

What else should I do to make the plugin working?

Grav 1.7.34

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is still NOT resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorisation must also be set at the page level, by adding the following to the frontmatter of the page:

```
access:
  site:
    login: true
```

What does `session:split`?

By default, an administrator has a different session when working in Admin (backend) and frontend (the site). This means an administrator has to login both to backend and frontend separately. When `false`, the same session will be used, which saves the administrator from logging in twice when login is requested by the page.

Comment: Yes, now it's working, thank you! I see that adding these lines to the frontmatter switches `page.template` to `login`. Is there a way to keep the real template of the current page?

Comment: @stckvrw, I don't see the template of the page changing. It remains `02.typography/default.md`. Also the look-and-feel of the page doesn't change. You might consider creating an issue at https://github.com/bleutzinn/grav-plugin-editable-contenttools to get an answer from the developer.